# Should I suspend a shelf from the ceiling?

Tags: ceiling, shelving

I have recently installed a new projector onto my back wall in my lounge.
See attached photo.

The problem I am having is weight - the main big board you can see in the picture is screwed into a window frame. Then as you can see I have created a shelf, and then projector hangs from that shelf. What is happening is that there is too much weight on the end of the shelf, which is making the shelf drop. My idea is to somehow attached a couple of strong wires to the shelf that is attached to the projector, and have those wires attach to the ceiling.

Ideally I would like to be able to turn some sort of adjustment that tightens the wire, just so I can get the perfect support.

Is this a good idea?

[image]

Comment: I'm curious as to why the shelf is so long.  You created a lever so that the force of the projector is greater than if directly under the supports.

Answer (score 4):

You COULD do that, [the adjusters-things you want are called turnbuckles] but it might be a lot simpler (no holes in the ceiling) to use better and larger shelf brackets. Better, in having a brace that makes them a triangle. Larger, making a larger, more stable triangle. A pair of good heavy duty brackets in a large size will make a shelf that you can sit on and not deflect - much less a measly projector. I had a clothes dryer mounted on this sort of bracket for years.

[image: Braced shelf bracket]

Comment: +1 (But no endorsement of the clothes dryer project). Also, no wire in the ceiling will do much good unless you hit a structural support with a good sized threaded device.

Comment: The shelf outlived the dryer - 15 years or so.

Comment: If you need a higher support, you might be better off putting a cable on an angle back into the corner of the ceiling and wall near the cove molding, again hitting a stud.

Comment: In addition, does the projector have to project (heh) so far from the wall? Moving it close to the wall will help with the weight issue as well.

Answer (score 4):

The room you're in has some nice crown moulding and probably is a nicely finished room - it's a shame (IMHO) to put in some crappy looking shelf brackets. Just to throw out an alternative suggestion, why not use a product meant for exactly this purpose?

There are wall and ceiling mounts for projectors, and look around online and you'll find these starting around the same cost as the parts you'll need to build a not-as-nice-looking shelf.

[image]
[image]

While you're at it, get some surface-mount conduit to hide the ugly wires. Many are paintable so they'll blend right in.

[image]